# How to ask permissions from a Service

Tags: android, service, permissions, locationmanager

I am implementing a service that uses LocationManager to get and utilize the tablet location. This service is start and stop from an activity.

The latest Android requires that permissions are requested on runtime. Now I have managed to do this on an activity by using `requestPermission` in `onCreate` , `checkSelfPermission` everytime I use some Location manager function, and adding the `requestPermission` function and overriding the `onRequestPermissionResult`.

It works great.

Now for my service I need to do the same, but these functions seems to work only for activities. *How can I activate permissions in a Service?*

---

just in case, I have already asked for permissions in the activity that starts and stops the services

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I activate permissions in a Service?

You don't. You activate (i.e., request) permissions from an activity. That is not negotiable.

Ideally, you request permissions before the activity starts the service or does something that will eventually cause the service to start (e.g., schedules the job with `JobScheduler`).

If you determine that your service no longer has the necessary permissions — perhaps the user revoked them from Settings — you could raise a `Notification` that leads the user to an activity where you re-request the permissions.

It is technically possible for a service to start an activity which requests the permissions. Usually, this is not a good idea, as you may not know what the user is doing at that moment, and the user may be unhappy to have you interrupt them with this permission request.

Comment: I can totally agree with that. My app actually has the structure of an activity - which successfully asks fro permissions- that later starts the service. Now *how* do I transfer those permissions to the service? (Ideally I want the service to run even after I close the activity)

Comment: @KansaiRobot: "Now how do I transfer those permissions to the service?" -- there is nothing to "transfer". Just start or bind to your service after having obtained the runtime permissions.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I activate permissions in a Service?

You can't request for permissions from services. Permissions should be asked explicitly which should be visible to the user in UI. However you can ask permission from activity and, if succeed, you can access those resources until user again turned off permission for your app.

> how can you "transfer" these permissions to the service?

Permission is assigned for the entire app, so you don't need to transfer it from one activity to another or from one activity to service. Once you get a permission in an Activity, that permission is assigned to the entire app and your services can access the resources then after. cheers :)

Comment: ok, I can understand that. If anything the structure of my app is ready for that.(activity already gets permissions and start a service). The question is *how* can you "transfer" these permissions to the service?